Why was the answer by the author (of the work) in a story-id question converted to a comment?
In the question Short story involving time dilation and a girl growing up while her astronaut mother explores other planets, the work has been positively identified (by the asker) as "Deuda Temporal" (translated to English "Borrowed Time"), by Cuban scifi author Anabel Enríquez Piñeiro.
The asker accepted their own answer (which is fine), but there's another answer by user AnEnriWriter -- who is Anabel herself! -- identifying her story and providing a link to Google Books for it, but this answer was deleted by Null and converted into a comment.
What's the policy being applied here? Why is the answer by the author of the work considered a "comment"?
Why I think it's a mistake:

It denies the author of the work potential reputation (while leaving other incorrect answers gathering upvotes).
The answer wasn't a comment, it truly provided context, who the translator was, in which English-language collection it can be found, and even provides a link to Google Books.


Update 2024-09-02:
I contacted the author using her LinkedIn profile, and she confirmed AnEnriWriter is her user, and that she wrote the story (and wrote the deleted answer).

How do you know that user is actually the author? The user claims to be, but I couldn't find any evidence in the profile.

@Null 1- assume good faith, 2- she provided additional information (like the collection where the English translation exists), 3- if you thought this wasn't the real author and her claims were false, converting to a comment wasn't the right choice; deleting was!

@Null "How do you know that user is actually the author?" Why do you even ask this, if later you claim even if I can find evidence this is the author, it wouldn't matter to you? Best not to ask a question if you consider the answer irrelevant...

@Null I contacted her on her LinkedIn profile, and she confirmed AnEnriWriter is her, and that she wrote the story: https://www.linkedin.com/in/anabelenriquez/

About the answerer being the author
Verifying that an Actual Author™ really is who they claim to be is a tricky issue, which has come up here multiple times over the years:

2013: What kind of proof is necessary when someone claims to be one of the creators of some work?
2016: Should we assume celebrity users are who they say they are?
2017: Should we accept "Word of God" type answers from users claiming to be Authors/Producers of a franchise?

It's tricky because there are dangers both ways. Obviously we don't want to blot out the contributions of actual authors to our site, events rare and exciting enough to be worth listing on meta. But if we agree to take on trust everyone who claims to be an author, that could and would be abused by trolls in obvious ways. Without having used any mod tools to investigate this user's identity, I do agree with you that they most likely are the author, as a guess based on the post they've provided. But let's all agree that we cannot allow any post content just because it's posted by the author of the work in question. Abusive content would be an obvious example (not that this has ever happened, to my knowledge, but it demonstrates the principle).
About the content of this particular post
You know the usual line about SE not being a discussion forum and answers being expected to be answers rather than commentary; I don't need to repeat that. For story-ID specifically, we therefore usually expect answers to positively identify the story ("the answer is Story X") as a bare minimum, hopefully also explain how that story fits the description in the question and other stuff too. If an answer has been correctly identified, then further answers like "I was looking for this story too" are usually deleted even if they do mention the name of the story, because they're redundant and the main point of such posts isn't actually to answer the question.
So what about this particular answer? Well, it's a bit of an edge case IMHO. On the one hand, the main purpose of the post seems to be commentary rather than providing an answer: "You really remember ... Did you locate it? You can find it at this link ..." On the other hand, the post does specify details about the story which weren't in the accepted answer, such as the translator and collection and editor, so it could potentially be seen as a reasonable answer after some editing, although it might attract community downvotes and delete-votes anyway.
About the mod action taken
As I said above, this is a bit of an edge case. Sometimes, edge cases are best left to the community rather than mod intervention being needed. But, as Null already said, this one warranted diamond intervention for two reasons: preserving the content as a comment would only be possible via a mod-only action, and a custom mod flag had already been raised (sending the post to the mod queue only rather than the community review queue).
Because it's an edge case, there's a number of different mod actions that could reasonably have been taken. Converting the answer to a comment; deleting it outright; editing it and dismissing the flag; ... I'm not sure what I would've done if I'd been the one handling that flag, but I don't think Null was wrong to do what he did. It was a reasonable action, not necessarily objectively the best, but a compromise between deleting the quasi-answer and preserving the content. It's reasonable to disagree with that action too, but I don't think it's fair to paint it as mod abuse or pettiness.

"the post does specify details about the story which weren't in the accepted answer, such as the translator and collection and editor". The accepted answer has a link to ISFDB, which does specify all these. It's arguably not in the answer since it's behind a link, but I didn't learn anything new from the post in question that I hadn't already learned from the accepted answer (because I viewed the ISFDB link).

@Null if it's behind the link but not in the answer, it's not part of the answer (for the same reason "link-only answers" are frowned up: things not in the text aren't part of the answer; the link just provides a reference). Can the accepted answer be improved to add this information to the forefront? Sure! And the same can be done to AnEnriWriter's answer: improving it instead of deleting it.

Thanks for the answer. I'm not arguing for letting in any content (abusive language seem like an odd example), but relevant content by the author. If I can confirm this is indeed the author, would this sway your opinion either way? (She hasn't replied on LinkedIn and there's a chance she never will, anyway. But what if she does confirm this is her?)

At the end of the day, I really don't see any downside. It strikes me as extremely unlikely that this individual really cares that their drive-by post is now a comment rather than answer.

@Valorum agreed about this. She seems to have made her account specifically for this question (likely her book came up in a Google search, and scifi.se ranks high). But just because she (likely) doesn't care doesn't mean it's right... I mean, what's the precedent here? What if it was Isaac Asimov, would his answer have been deleted or improved? (If he was alive, of course!)

@AndresF. "If I can confirm this is indeed the author, would this sway your opinion either way?" - for me personally, no. As I said, I already do believe this is the author, based on the content of the post.

And yet Terry Brown's answer to this question was not deleted or converted, and received 39 upvotes and no downvotes. What is the big difference between the two cases?

@user14111 That's a fair question, I'm not sure really. It was never flagged for mod attention, for one thing.

@user14111 I'll have to be honest, when I saw it appear the first time, I hesitated to flag it because it doesn't seem to answer the question in any meaningful way but seemed to be accepted by those from the community who saw it. The information can be useful to some extent but it's definitely not a direct answer to the question. It's more of a forum post, which Stack Exchange sites aren't.

@Clockwork I think Terry's answer was accepted (I upvoted it) because while technically redundant, it's still a nice answer-comment, and it makes the site better. I prefer a world where I can find direct posts by scifi authors on scifi.se than one where "the rules" state they will be deleted unless this-or-that. Again, excluding obviousy unwanted answers like abuse or spam, or random nonsense. I mean, an author taking their time to comment/answer here about their own work is qualitatively different than an unrelated person doing the same, and should have some leeway.

I'm reminded of a story where a living Homo neanderthalensis goes to an anthropology conference and is poorly received because he lacks academic credentials. Also reminded of a quotation from somewhere, "the letter killeth but the spirit giveth life."

Well, not that anybody cares by now, but I contacted the author using her LinkedIn profile, and she confirmed AnEnriWriter is her user, and that she wrote the story: linkedin.com/in/anabelenriquez

For those who cannot see deleted posts, this is the text of the post in question:

You really remember my short story, "Borrowed Time" :)("Deuda temporal" in Spanish). Yes, it's a translation by Professor Daniel W. Koon for the compilation The ApexBook of World SF II edited by Lavie Tidhar. I'm glad to find a reader who pays so much attention to details. Did you locate it? You can find it at this link on Google Books. Thank you for being so interested in my little story.
https://books.google.com/books?id=K-WxS8n0RTMC&lpg=PA130&ots=y_umB0K39X&dq=anabel%20enr%C3%ADquez%20pi%C3%B1eiro&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=anabel%20enr%C3%ADquez%20pi%C3%B1eiro&f=false

This post was brought to my attention by a flag requesting that it be converted to a comment. In reviewing the post, I noted that none of the information was new except for the Google Books link: the accepted answer linked to ISFDB which included

the original title in Spanish
the name of the translator
the collection in which the story appeared, and its editor

The accepted answer also included quotes from the story with matching text from the question, but the post in question did not.
The answerer claims to be the story's author, but I could find no evidence in the profile to support that claim (I simply viewed the profile -- I did not use any moderator-only tools to attempt to confirm the user's identity).
Given that the post was flagged it's likely that it would eventually be flagged for deletion by some user with that privilege. If that happened, it's possible that other users would also vote to delete it. However, since the post did contain one piece of new, useful information (the Google Books link) and only moderators can convert posts to comments, I reasoned that it was best to convert the post to a comment in order to preserve that link even if users decided to delete the post as a low-quality answer.
I don't have a particularly strong opinion whether the post should be left as an answer or converted to a comment, but I also don't find the unsubstantiated claim of authorship a compelling reason to leave it as an answer. I upvoted the question and accepted answer, but I did not and would not upvote the post in question as originally posted since it is almost entirely covered by the accepted answer.

As the user who raised the flag my reasoning follows yours quite closely. If there wasn’t an already accepted answer then I’d have neatened it a bit and given it an up vote. But it did have the link so wasn’t worth getting rid of completely.

@Null the author is on LinkedIn, the only contact I can find. She seems to be notesworthy in the Spanish-speaking scifi community (more than 1 publication, articles written by her, etc.). If I can get her to say she's one and the same person as AnEnriWriter, would you be willing to undelete her answer? It doesn't matter if the other answer is more elaborate, we do not tend to delete redundant answers unless they are poor quality. And giving rep points to the author for her own work seems right; the contrary seems petty. So would you be willing, if I get her to confirm it's her?

@fez If we confirm AnEnriWritter is the author of the scifi story, would you still flag her answer? Seems petty to me, especially since an incorrect answer is still there with upvotes, but the author cannot get upvotes from her own (and correct) answer! (I've contacted her on LinkedIn, let's see if she answers. She doesn't seem to be very active over there either...)

@AndresF. I still don't think it's a particularly useful answer. It is essentially just saying "the story can be read at [Google Books link]", which we tend to accept as comments but not as answers. I do see redundant story ID answers (especially when there is an accepted answer) tend to be deleted by the community. It's a good comment for the link, but as-is I wouldn't upvote it as an answer even if I knew it was from the author.

@Null so basically your objection that the author cannot be verified is just an afterthought? You decided to delete without due diligence to verify her identity. Here's what would make sense to me: improve the author's response if we must (like we do with all answers) and let her gain reputation from her own work. If we want to be a welcoming community and not petty, that is. Your answer still doesn't explain why you'd let an incorrect answer earn upvotes (remember: incorrect is worse than correct but incomplete) but have the correct answer by the work's author deleted.

(Also, seems like an abuse of mod powers: you deleted and I cannot undelete. Your rapid deletion had almost no consensus to it, and mod intervention wasn't needed  -- speedy deletions are for things that are egregiously wrong, like spam, not for this. If I could undelete it, we could go over a proper debate about whether your action was appropriate or not. Now we cannot.)

@AndresF. - who posted the answer is irrelevant, I reviewed based on the content. And wrong answers shouldn’t be deleted just because they’re wrong, however, duplicated answers that basically add nothing to the existing accepted one, typically are

@fez who says the word of the author is irrelevant? Who decided this? It's only irrelevant for a mechanical, heartless website. For a website for real scifi enthusiasts, surely the Word of the Author is valuable. This was an actual answer, not a comment, and it provided context/details not in the accepted answer. It's not even true we delete answers which redundant; that's not a current policy. And because it was speedily deleted, nobody who's not a mod or has enough rep can even see it now; most people won't object now because they cannot even see it. It seems a misuse of mod power.

Honestly, it's as if there's a bit of moving the goalpost/gaslighting going on here. First it's "we're not even sure this is the author". Then it's "ok, even if it's the author  it's not an answer". Then it's "ok, even if it's an answer, it's redundant". What's going to be the objection next, so that I can prepare? I can only echo my sentiment when Danny Rubin got downvoted after answering a question of Groundhog Day, the movie whose script he helped write: "only in scifi.se!".

@AndresF. It is not my responsibility to confirm a user's claim to be an author. Any random user on the Internet can trivially claim to be the author of any work, but it takes effort to confirm that unless the claimant provides evidence. The burden of proof is on the one who wishes to reap the benefits of being recognized as an author.

@AndresF. Can we calm down a bit here? I've just come across this meta post, but I'm already seeing multiple accusations of pettiness and mod abuse flying around. The way the system works is that posts deleted by diamond mods can't be undelete-voted by non-mods; that doesn't mean a diamond deletion is an abuse of mod power, just because you can't vote to undo that action. And before you ask, Null didn't ping me or ask me to weigh in - there's no mod conspiracy here, I've just seen this meta post and I'm going to post my view shortly.

@AndresF. Even story authors must abide by the rules of the site. An author cannot post gibberish or a mere comment as an answer to a question about his or her work. I judged the post in question to be a comment rather than an answer -- it doesn't matter if it was posted by the story author if it is a comment.

@AndresF. I added the text of the post in question so everyone can see it and debate as you wish.

@Randal'Thor I'm not upset, and these are not accusations. These are my claims:

A question about the author's identity was made, which made me go try contact her, but then it turns out the answer to this question wasn't relevant.
A mod deleted a question (a "speedy deletion", which wasn't warranted) preventing all possible discussions about it. I understand speedy deletions as tools to remove insults/spam/etc, not valid but potentially redundant answers. What need is there for speed?
If this is the author, preventing her from gaining rep seems petty.
Does my summary seem fair?


@Randal'Thor who needs calming down now? :) I'm a veteran of scifi.se (as you can attest), I know there are no "mod conspiracies" nor did I made any such deranged claim. I thought Null was in the wrong, that's about it. Don't make me sound crazy, address my objections instead!

@AndresF. I did not delete the post to prevent the user (whether or not she is the author) from gaining rep, I did so as I explained in my answer here: to ensure the Google Books link wasn't lost if the post was deleted. Posts can be undeleted and I've copied the text for everyone to see, so it's absolutely untrue that deleting the post is "preventing all possible discussions about it" (and, obviously, we're discussing it right now). As for the "speedy" deletion, it is generally desirable for mods to handle flags in a "speedy" manner.

@Randal'Thor - We're one short of the full set of moderators telling us that there is no conspiracy here ;-)

@Null gotcha, but I didn't mean you actively wanted to prevent the author from gaining rep (why would you? You've never heard of her before). I'm just arguing your action had the unintended consequence of denying her potential rep. It seems a posteriori unkind and seems like a bad precedent. I'm not saying you did this on purpose, just that it's mistaken. I'm not claiming conspiracy here, just a mistake and a bad precedent to set...

@Valorum which is bizarre, isn't it? Now it seems I'm claiming conspiracy when I just complained about the actions of a single mod... oh, well.

@AndresF. You said "preventing her from gaining rep seems petty" and that flagging her answer "seems petty". I can't think of a way to act "petty" without willfully doing so, so it sounds like you are accusing me (and the flagger) of "actively want[ing] to prevent the author from gaining rep". As I've said from the beginning I don't really care whether the post is a comment or answer, I just handled the flag to the best of my judgment. I won't lose any sleep if the community prefers to see it as an answer or another mod undeletes it unilaterally. You're making a mountain out of a molehill.

@AndresF. I never accused you of claiming conspiracy, just wanted to pre-empt such claims as I realised that I was commenting at almost exactly the same time as Null. (Btw, you wouldn't believe how many times I've gone to delete a flagged comment only to see "deleted by Null 7 seconds ago" on it.)

@Null if that's what it sounded like, let me put that fear to rest: I'm not accusing you or fez of actively trying to prevent anyone of anything. I'm saying that you made a mistake, and that the precedent this sets is petty. No, I don't think either you or fez are malicious or have a vendetta against someone you'd never heard of before today. Hope this clears the misconception.

The mod-deleted answer actually contains quite a bit more information than the accepted answer, not to mention the incorrect answer. It has the name of the translator, the collection it can be found in, and the Google Books link. The accepted answer mentions none of this. (The link to isfdb does not mean that the accepted answer somehow magically includes all the information from that external database. Links are supporting evidence for answers, not answers in and of themselves.)
